# open Print Server Properties menu with C#

Tags: c#, windows, printing

I'm looking for a way to open with C# "Print Server Properties Menu"

With the following code i can open the setting menu for printers:

```
Process.Start("ms-settings:printers");
```

I can't find what code i need to open the "print server properties menu"

[image: Print Server Properties Menu]

Comment: last question, how can i return to the programm i was running? when i add your code and after closing the form. Windows goes to another openend programm

Comment: instead of using the static method Start of the Process class, you can create an instance of Process and then subscribe to its Exited event. In the Exited event handler you can force the focus back to your application. I would probably use WaitForExit() after starting the process, so the main application would block until the setting menu is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can load printui.dll with the rundll32 library loader and execute PrintUIEntry with the /s flag:

```
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "rundll32",
                Arguments = "printui.dll, PrintUIEntry /s",
                UseShellExecute = false
            };
            Process.Start(psi);
```

This can help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rundll32-printui